# What is the quickest way to allocate a set of points to a fixed number groups based on Euclidean distances from a point in each group?

Tags: algorithms, code-generation

Example, if i have certain geographic points in an array A=[a,b,c,d...n] and have 10 points distributed in the solution space B= [1,2,3...10], how can I allocate each member of A to the nearest point in B in the quickest way.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Programming questions are off-topic, here. We're happy to help with algorithms but implementing something in a specific language isn't something we do, here.

Comment: Are the values in `A` numeric, or characters as you have typed? How can you define what the "nearest point" is in this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "geographic points:?  by "solution space"?  What have you tried?  What approaches have you considered, and why did you reject them?

Comment: @David this can be in any language.  @ Jaken the values in A are geographic coordinates for example (120.2, 130.5) representing x and y respectively. The same case goes for the values in B. By nearest point, I meant for the values in A which pint is closest in terms of Euclidean distance

Comment: @David please edit your question to contain all necessary information. People are not expected to read the comments to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks very much like the [Nearest neighbor problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search). The asymptotically most efficient approach is probably computing a k-d-tree on the points in B. Constructing the tree takes $O(|B| \log |B|)$ and lookup is logarithmic, so an additional $O(|A| \log |A|)$ to find all nearest neighbours.

Please not that the constant factors for the naive approach where you just compute the distance to each point in B and take the minimum are really good. CPUs are very good at just summing squared differences. In practice it will be hard to beat that unless B is really huge.

Comment: A note that the quoted running time is valid in 2 dimensions, but in higher dimensions this is not valid.